# how to set environment type?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I have a Sinatra application that uses `sinatra/config_file` to parse a YAML configuration file. The file has entries for various environments such as development, test, production.

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::ConfigFile
  config_file 'config.yml'
  @@client = Mysql2::EM::Client.new(
      :host => settings.host,
      :username => settings.username,
      :password => settings.password,
      :database => settings.database
  )
```

Currently when I run the application, the settings are retrieved from the development section. And the only way that I found to make it use a different one was to set

```
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'production'
```

in my `myapp.rb` file.

I do not like editing source, how do I set the environment the proper way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Sinatra documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Environments), you can run your app in a different environment by using an argument at the command line, as such:

`ruby my_app.rb -e [ENVIRONMENT]`.